# How to label tasks so they appear in multiple teams' agile boards?

Tags: jira, scrum

We have two scrum teams working on a common product, so we have some cross-platform tasks that could apply to either team.

How would I create a label that would allow the task to appear in all backlogs/boards?

Comment: Each board has filter behind it. You need something in the filter that is common for all tasks - for example Component

Answer (score 0):

The issues that appear on a board are defined by a JQL filter. Typically this will simply select all the issues for a given project like this:

> project = "myproject"

But there is nothing stopping you from modifying it. As an example a board filter could use:

> project = "myproject" or labels in ("mylabel")

That would show all the issues for the project 'myproject' and any issues that include a label 'mylabel'.

The board filter can be modified in the 'Configure' menu on the board under 'General'.

Answer (score 0):

I am using currently the field label, and each team agile board will use it to filter their own user stories  and by putting both team names  (team_1, team_2) on the user story label, both teams will see the same user story.